# python scrapy decoding to json even when value field contains a single quotes

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm working on python web scraping and I would like to decode a string to json format. But I can't do it, since some of the value fields in the string contains single quotes in it.

For example, this is the string from the web page, I want to decode to json:

```
dataLayer = [{'place': 'paris', 
        'description': 'its one of the world's beautiful places.' }]
```

Since the description field contains a single quotes inside it (**world's**), I can't decode it to json.

This is my code:

```
import re
import cjson
place_details = re.findall("dataLayer = \[(.*?)\];", response.body, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)[0].replace("\'", "\"")
place_details_json = cjson.decode(("{"+product_details+"}"))
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's a big of a mess to try to untangle. Depending on the other places you have `'` in your dataset, you may get away with something as simple as this:

```
>>> s="""{'place': 'paris', 
...             'description': 'its one of the world's beautiful places.' }"""
>>> import re, json
>>> json.loads(re.sub(r"('\B)|(\B')", '"', s))
{'place': 'paris', 'description': "its one of the world's beautiful places."}
```

"scrapy" is the key word when text hasn't been escaped correctly!

Comment: Thank you john for your help. It worked. Now im wondering what if a double quote comes in place for a single quote? Is it possible to load it to json?

Comment: @nithinks, you'll need to create a test suite of samples that covers all the variations you're seeing. Then you can work on solving all those other special cases.

Answer (score -1):

```
import json
print json.dumps(dataLayer)
```

Because `dumps()` for non-ASCII characters return value to unicode.